# Cookies logout razor remove

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an asp application and i need to remove all current session's cookies in the action of logout:

```
 public ActionResult Logout()
        {
            Upload.Models.CompteModels.Connected = false;
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
         }
```

Now i use a static class `CompteModels` with a boolean to test if the user is authentifying or not but it's not efficent. so i think that i have to remove all cookies when i logout.

How can i do it?

Comment: what authentication method are you using?

Comment: ` [AllowAnonymous]
 public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
  {
  string _login = Request.Params["Pseudo"];
  string _password = Request.Params["Password"];
  if (_login != null)
  {
   Upload.Models.LoginModel model = new LoginModel();
   string s = model.authentifier(_login, _password);
   if (s != "false")
    {
   Upload.Models.CompteModels.Connected = true;
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
                }
                else return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }`

Comment: I mean are you using forms, windows or some other authentication method

Comment: and your login method does not look correct.

Comment: no it is correct and i'am loging without problem. but my problem is how can block the come back in the browser : if i were connected and i click into back button in the browser, i stay in the same page and i will not redirect to the page of authentification

Comment: i dont mean incorrect as in does not work i mean incorrect as in not the correct way to action what you are trying. I would seriously read some MVC tutorials and read Darins http://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov posts on MVC. You will then see what i mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A static property is shared across all users, so using a static property to determine if a user is logged in will not work correctly, as this would log out all users, or log them in.

You can abandon the session using `Session.Abandon` or remove a cookie using the `HttpResponse.Cookies` collection, and write a cookie to it that is expired.

Comment: i think the op's issues are deeper than this one question i think a fundamental lack of understanding of MVC is the main obstacle, having reviewed their other questions it seems apparent that they don't really understand how ASP.NET-MVC works.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean drop session data and remove the sessions cookies see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069003/force-users-to-logout) for how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a session variable called LoggedIn or something similar and just clear this in your logout action. Then in your Login action you need to check for this session.

```
 public ActionResult Logout()
 {
    Upload.Models.CompteModels.Connected = false;
    Session.Remove("LoggedIn");
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
 }

 public ActionResult Login()
 {
    // check for session var, redirect to landing page maybe?
    if(Session["LoggedIn"] == null) 
    {
       RedirectToAction("Home", "Index");
    }
    else
    {
       Session.Add("LoggedIn", true);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("TargetPage", "TargetAction");
 }
```

Just one idea, depends on where you want users to be redirected to and such, `TargetPage` could be an admin area or something similar.